# Remove all occurances of class in angular 2 +

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have just started coding in angular5 and I came across need of removing all class occurances on click event.
Something like below we have in Jquery

```
$('.m-active').removeClass('m-active');
```

I am looking for alternative of this in angular2 + (Typescript)

Answer (score 2):

You could use document.querySelector all to remove the class - in the following - I have two divs - iniitally set to be red / green text, but using querySelectorAll - I am removing the red class from the divs.

```js
function toggleRedClass() {
var redDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.red');

if (redDivs.length) {
  for(i=0;i<redDivs.length;i++) {
    redDivs[i].classList.remove('red');
    redDivs[i].classList.add('black')
  }
} else {
  var blackDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.black');
   for(i=0;i<blackDivs.length;i++) {
   blackDivs[i].classList.remove('black')
    blackDivs[i].classList.add('red')
  }
  }
}
```

```css
.red {color:red}
.green {color:green}
```

```html
<div class="red">test</div>
<div class="green">test1</div>

<button type="button" onclick="toggleRedClass()">Click to toggle the red class</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 2+ better use bindings instead of jQuery

```
<div [class.my-class]="isMyClass">div 1</div>
<div [class.my-class]="isMyClass">div 2</div>
<button (click)="isMyClass = !isMyClass">toggle</button>
```

```
export class MyComponent {
  isMyClass:boolean = true;
}
```

Comment: I got your solution. but it won't work for me as I am using class to toggle components based on condition so removing that class and adding it would work for me the way we have for jQuery

Comment: `isMyClass` is the condition. Perhaps you can share more details about your requirements to make it easier to discuss.

Comment: I have component c1 where on click event I am hiding it, I have component c2 on click of that I would hide c2 and will like to show c1 , but I guess removeclass won't work here since those components are unaware of each other

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to create a http://stackblitz.com reproduction. I don't think this is hard to achieve with simple Angular bindings. You should probably manage the condition on the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive like this :

https://plnkr.co/edit/eKokX0IrsIWIuY9ACUZ4?p=preview

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[class]'
})
export class ClassDirective {
  @Input('class') claz;
  private _claz;
  public set claz(claz){
     this._claz = claz;
  }
  public get claz(){
    return this._claz;
  }
  @HostBinding('class') get hostClass(){
    return this.claz;
  }
  constructor(){
    console.log('***');
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log('this.classz',this.claz);
    setTimeout(()=>{

      this.claz= this.claz.replace('milad','');
    },2000)
  }
}
```

I know it doesn't do exactly what you want, but the idea is to create a Directive which has a selector called `class` and then you have access to all the classes in your application (obviously this component should be declared in your modules).

Then you can do whatever you'd like inside that directive, you can use host binding to override the classes and whatnot.

You can create an event listener to some button, pass the event listener's call back to this directive and let it do whatever you want.